# How to forward same image to output of my telegram bot written in PHP?

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am not able to process the user provided image to forward same image in bot output. if user sent only text to the bot, all worked without any issues. But when user provide a photo with text to the bot, it doesn't work as expected.

Using below code

```
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot(token)/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".urlencode($text));
```

i also tried sendphoto funtion but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you use not correct method to send message with photo. You should use `sendPhoto` not `sendMessage`. To forward photo to other user using telegram bot, you should find out link of it, just check the format in which the message with the photo arrives, there will be the link as well.

For example I am using curl PHP method to send "POST" request not "GET":

```
// $path - link of the image
// $bot_token - token of the bot
// $msg - text of your message
// $id - chat id for sending
// $kb - keyboard for message

function botSendPhoto($path, $bot_token, $msg = null, $id = false, $kb = null, $bot_id = 0) {
  exec_time();
  if (is_array($msg)) {
    $msg = implode("\n", $msg);
  }
    
  $post = [
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
    'disable_web_page_preview' => 'true',
    'chat_id' => $id,
    'caption' => $msg,
    'photo' => $path,
  ];
  if ($kb) {
    $post['reply_markup'] = json_encode(botKeybd($kb));
  }
  $res = json_decode(req(botUrl('sendPhoto', $bot_token), $post), true);
    
  return $res;
}
```